# Mobile app moment is not a function

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

I have updated SDK to 6.3.0.GA and started getting "moment is not a function".  I have checked Resources folder, moment.js is zero byte. Please help how to fix this.

Comment: Did you try again after a clean rebuild? Also share some code snippets & directory-structure of your app so we can know you are using code properly.

Comment: how are you including moment in your code?

Answer (score 4):

Clean Project; delete build and resources directories. Build project again and "moment is not a function" disappears